# JQUERY код срабатывает только со второго раза

Tags: javascript, jquery

Довольно распространенная на JQ ошибка - код срабатывает только со второго нажатия на элемент.
Функцию запускал при помощи CLICK и ON, но код срабатывает только со второго раза. Причина судя по всему в функции .data() но не знаю как исправить код чтобы он работал как надо.
из атрибута DATA-price мы берем текст и вставляем в нужное место.

Помогите исправить

```js
$("ul li").on( "click",function(){
 var a=$(this).data( "price" );
 $(".row.active .price").html(a);
 $("ul li").removeClass("active");
 $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Конкретно в приведенном коде никакой ошибки нет, он отлично срабатывает с первого раза, где-то в другом месте что-то у вас

Comment: добавьте html иначе не понятно

Comment: спасибо Вадиму за подсказку, оказалось косяк мой. Не был внимателен в написании селекторов

Answer (score 1):

все работает и  с первого раза:

```js
$("ul li").on( "click",function(){
 var a=$(this).data( "price" );
 $(".row.active .price").html(a);
 $("ul li").removeClass("active");
 $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    lorem
  </li>
  <li>
    ipsum
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: а вас не смущает что в коде на JS, какой-то data-price целых 2 строчки занимает? может выпилить эти строчки, всё равно в вашем примере они не используются

Comment: @MasterAlex, а Вас не смущает что они в условии вопроса стоят (эти 2 строчки) ? Структура html выбрана мной произвольна, потому что автор не привел свой html код (возможно в нем причина проблемы).

Comment: я спросил не про вопрос, а про ответ, ваш ответ содержит код из вопроса, но вы его не используете по назначению, а именно вытаскивание дата-атрибута и вставка в нужный блок. Зачем тогда вообще нужен ваш ответ с простейшей покраской текста по клику?

Comment: Что считаю нужным то и добавляю в код! И все работает!

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось код и правда работает. по началу мешал скрипт который использовал такойже селектор.
После переделки селектора оказалось что внутренний селектор (строка скрипта - 3) выбирает самый первый элемент на странице и изменяет значение в нем, и только со второго раза в нужном элементе.
После добавления правильного селектора код заработал как надо